# Cannot click or use keyboard on x11vnc connection to Ubuntu 20.04 from Mac Screen Sharing App

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop, vnc

I am using a vpn to connect my Macbook Air to my linux desktop, using x11vnc. This is the command I run **from the linux desktop**:

`x11vnc -display :0 -noxrecord -forever -passwd 123456`

From mac I open the "Screen Sharing" app (not "Apple Remote Desktop") and connect using the linux machine's vpn-assigned IP address, port 5900. I put in the password `123456` and it connects.

**I can move the mouse but I cannot click or type**

Btw the vpn I'm using is ZeroTier.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @blueether It just started working out of nowhere one day